# How can I copy filenames from a folder in my computer to a newly created excel sheet usng java?

Tags: java

Below is the following code: I have first made a new csv excel file and then tried to copy the files inside DemoFiles(which is in my Desktop) inside newly created Excel File. But it is not copying any of the contents.

```
  
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
 
public class FileListFromFolder {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {


        
          //Create Blank workbook
          XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

          //Create file system using specific name
          FileOutputStream ExcelFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/Users/nikhil/Desktop/hello.csv"));

          //write operation workbook using file out object
          workbook.write(ExcelFile);
          ExcelFile.close();
          System.out.println("createworkbook.xlsx written successfully");
       
    
          File SourceFile = new File("C:/Users/nikhil/Desktop/DemoFiles");
          File TargetExcelFile = new File("C:/Users/nikhil/Desktop/hello.csv");
          
          try
          {
              Files.copy(SourceFile.toPath(), ExcelFile);
          }
          
          catch(Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Error");
          }

    }
}
```

Comment: In `Files.copy(SourceFile.toPath(), ExcelFile);`, firstly the SourceFile is a directory and you can't just read it as if it was a text file. Secondly, the target, ExcelFile, was already closed and therefore can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:
`Files.copy( originalPath, TargetExcelFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);`

Comment: I think you also should use next
Files.copy(SourceFile.toPath(), TargetExcelFile);